# Mysql query not using index

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a quite big order table in mysql (about 120k lines, and growing) and i see in the mysql-slow log some queries are taking too long.
Also i have some peaks loads in the server due to this.

One of the queries:

```
SELECT [list of fields] 
FROM   orders o 
       LEFT JOIN orders_total ot 
              ON ( o.orders_id = ot.orders_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN orders_status s 
              ON o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id 
WHERE  s.language_id = '3' 
       AND ot.class = 'ot_total' 
       AND ( o.customers_name LIKE '%126627%' 
              OR o.customers_company LIKE '%126627%' 
              OR o.orders_id LIKE '%126627%' 
              OR o.delivery_name LIKE '%126627%' 
              OR o.delivery_company LIKE '%126627%' 
              OR o.customers_email_address LIKE '%126627%' 
              OR o.customers_telephone LIKE '%126627%' 
              OR o.billing_name LIKE '%126627%' 
              OR o.billing_company LIKE '%126627%' 
              OR o.billing_nif LIKE '%126627%' ) 
ORDER  BY o.orders_id DESC 
LIMIT  0, 20;
```

Made an explain of these queries and got this:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  o   index   PRIMARY,order_status    PRIMARY 4   NULL    127733  Using where
1   SIMPLE  s   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   o.orders_status,const   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  ot  ref idx_orders_total_orders_id  idx_orders_total_orders_id  4   o.orders_id 4   Using where
```

As you can see the query is going throught all the records of table orders.

Table order's got `orders_status` index.

How can avoid this?
Its an `MyISAM` table, making it an `InnoDB` will solve this peak loads?

Thanks

Comment: The string searches in that query `... LIKE '%126627%'` are not sargable, so will lead to terrible performance if there are many rows that match on the other criteria.  You may want to consider using a fulltext index, or a search engine like Solr or Sphinx.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, right table conditions in the WHERE clause make the outer join work as an inner join, i.e. move "s.language_id = '3'" to the ON clause instead, and also move "ot.class = 'ot_total'". (If you need an outer join...!)

Comment: All conditions column_name like '%pattern%' use full scan. You need show us some additional information like tables difinition and example of real sql query if you want give help.

Comment: As jarlh says the outer join on orders_status, then filtering on s.language_id is odd. Same with orders_total and class. Either those LEFT joins should be INNER, or the language_id and class conditions should be part of the outer join conditions.

Comment: The solution  is actually to normalize the database, and create another table which will connect all those ids from the patterns in WHERE clause with specific records in your orders table.

Comment: @newtover: What if the patterns are unpredictable, e.g. derived from user-provided search queries?

Comment: @eggyal, then the performance of the queries is usually not a problem.

Comment: @eggyal i'll try to make a full text index. But will this slow down the performance?

Comment: @jarlh i've put the language_id and class as outer join conditions but does not improve performance.

Comment: @rekobeko, outer join does never improve performance - it gives a different result!!! (At least in many cases, data dependent...)

Comment: @jarlh i do not have any diffetent result thanks for your help

Comment: Then you can do an INNER JOIN. (May even improve performance in your specific case.)

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not fix your query, but the `left join`s should be inner `join`s.  They are being turned into inner joins by the `where` clause anyway.

See what the explain is for this version of the query:

```
SELECT [list of fields] 
FROM orders o JOIN
     orders_total ot 
     ONo.orders_id = ot.orders_id JOIN
     orders_status s 
     ON o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id 
WHERE s.language_id = '3' AND ot.class = 'ot_total' AND
      (o.customers_name LIKE '%126627%' OR
       o.customers_company LIKE '%126627%' OR
       o.orders_id LIKE '%126627%' OR
       o.delivery_name LIKE '%126627%' OR
       o.delivery_company LIKE '%126627%' OR
       o.customers_email_address LIKE '%126627%' OR
       o.customers_telephone LIKE '%126627%' OR
       o.billing_name LIKE '%126627%' OR
       o.billing_company LIKE '%126627%' OR
       o.billing_nif LIKE '%126627%'
      ) 
ORDER BY o.orders_id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Note:  also check if `s.language_id` is a string or a number.  If it is a number, drop the single quotes.  Sometimes these can affect optimization.

Assuming you have the right indexes (such as `orders(orders_id, status_id)`, `orders_total(class, order_id)`, `order_status(order_status_id)`), there are still several ways that the query can be run.

Because you have other conditions besides the extensive `like` clauses, the query does not *have* to do a full table scan.  A big question, though, is how selective the other two conditions are (on class and status).  My guess is that these are no very selective -- i.e., more than 1% of the rows match those conditions.  The optimizer is deciding that scanning the tables is the most efficient way to resolve this query.

By the way, the `like` conditions look highly suspect.  If you are looking for words in character fields, you might consider full text search, which is much faster.